# Task List in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list, powershell, pnp-powershell

I want to export the task list which has enabled Send e-mail when ownership is assigned in the list using PowerShell:

```
$ctx=Get-PnPContext
$Lists = Get-PnPList 
$ctx.Load($Liss)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($List in $Lists){

    $Email = $List.EnableAssignToEmail
    $ctx.Load($Email)
    $ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    if($Email =$True){
       Write-Host $Emai.Title
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below PnP PowerShell command to check if E-Mail Notification is enabled on task list:

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity Tasks -Include EnableAssignToEmail 
$list.EnableAssignToEmail
```

Where `Tasks` is name of list.

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Get-PnPList](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnplist)

---

Follow below article to export list items to CSV:

[Export SharePoint Online List Items To CSV Using PnP PowerShell](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/export-sharepoint-online-list-items-to-csv-using-pnp-powershell)

Comment: This is correct answer. Fulfill the requirement

Comment: one thing, when i connected the site with on prem it is throwing error for email enable The EnableAssignToEmail field or property does not exist.. can you pls tell me why?